# ",(?!.*\\))" returning "Invalid Regex" error in R

Tags: regex, r, string, escaping

I've got a string that I'm working with and I'm trying to select only the commas that are outside of the parentheses so that I can split the string based on that. Here's the string I'm working with:

> "LIVINGSTON (Townships of Brighton, Deerfield, Genoa, Hartland,, Oceola & Tyrone), MACOMB, MONROE, OAKLAND, SANILAC, ST. CLAIR, AND WAYNE COUNTIES"

I'm trying to use the regex mentioned in the question title and it's telling me that it's not valid. Presumably this is because the closing parenthesis that is supposed to be escaped is being recognized by R as the parenthesis closing the match group and so the second parenthesis is throwing everything off. I'm just curious about how to work around this. Here is the syntax I'm using:

```
counties <- "LIVINGSTON (Townships of Brighton, Deerfield, Genoa, Hartland,, Oceola & Tyrone), MACOMB, MONROE, OAKLAND, SANILAC, ST. CLAIR, AND WAYNE COUNTIES"
tmp <- strsplit(counties, ',(?!.*\\))')
```

I can obviously just do the inverse of what I'm doing now and instead of splitting the text on the commas outside of the parentheses, simply replace the commas inside of the parentheses and then split the string on commas, but I'd like to know why this isn't working.

Comment: Turns out just setting `perl=T` fixes the problem.

Comment: substr() doesn't take a `perl=` argument, so the solution I added below I'd still argue is necessary.

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens I think substr is a typo by the op since running the code in the question doesnt give the invalid regex error

Comment: @rawr Thank you for pointing that out, yes it was a typo. So sorry for the confusion! I've edited the question to reflect the right question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason your regex isn't working is because it's very Perl-ish, which requires the perl=T flag.  I think it is also slightly malformed in that you should check for opening and closing parentheses to be complete...  I think this is a general solution matching not just your specific case:

```
counties <- "LIVINGSTON (Townships of Brighton, Deerfield, Genoa, Hartland,, Oceola & Tyrone), MACOMB, MONROE, OAKLAND, SANILAC, ST. CLAIR, AND WAYNE COUNTIES"
tmp <- strsplit(counties, ",(?![^(]*\\))", perl=T)
```

Comment: This solution works, so I've accepted it as the answer. But for anyone who might find this question in the future, I wanted to note that the regex in this solution and the regex in the original question provide the same result. It seems that adding `perl=T` is the only thing that changes it from invalid regex to "R-compliant" regex.

Comment: Thanks @brittenb, just to note, the `perl=T` argument actually just tells R to parse the regex as a Perl-like regular expression.  It's not peculiar to R, or "R-compliant" in that sense.  R has engines for two variants of regex, POSIX and Perl, which are alike in many respects but allow for different character class representations.

Comment: I didn't know about the engines for the two variants, so that's good information to have; I was simply pointing out that the changing the regex to include the opening parens didn't change the outcome. My goal was to reinforce the idea that R needs to interpret it as Perl regex to work. Again, thanks for the input and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an unbalanced `)`,

https://regex101.com/r/jE0lI9/1

should be:

```
counties <- "LIVINGSTON (Townships of Brighton, Deerfield, Genoa, Hartland,, Oceola & Tyrone), MACOMB, MONROE, OAKLAND, SANILAC, ST. CLAIR, AND WAYNE COUNTIES"
tmp <- substr(counties, ',(?!.*\\)')
```

Comment: I acknowledge that I have an unbalanced ")" in the question. The second ")" is supposed to close the matching group whereas the first ")" is supposed to be part of the regex.

Comment: while youre correct about the perl part, this is still invalid r code and does not work

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood the question correctly, try this:

```
strsplit(gsub("\\(.*\\)", "", counties), ",")[[1]]
```

Comment: That solution would work if not for one caveat: I need the text in the parentheses to be included with the first county. Otherwise that would be exactly what I need.